# How to get pages id in array in get_pages?

Tags: customization

```
$page1 = get_option('home_page_field');
$page2 = get_option('home_page_field1');
$page3 = get_option('home_page_field2');
$page4 = get_option('home_page_field3');


 $arrData = array( $page1, $page2 , $page3 );
```

its giving o/p as

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [text_string] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [text_string] => 499 ) [2] => Array ( [text_string] => 869 ) )
```

how can i set get_pages function to get the all info about the pages with these pages ids with me

PLease help 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `include` argument (see [`get_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) in Codex for details and examples) to retrieve specific set. To continue your snippet that would be:

```
$pages = get_pages( array(
    'include' => $arrData,
) );
```